# jQuery autocomplete and getJSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I want to use jquery autocomplete plugin with cooperation with jquery GetJson
In my client page i have the following code:

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              var test;
              $.getJSON("getData.aspx", function (json) {
                  alert("function dome");
test=json;
              });
              $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
                  source: test
              });
          });

      </script>
```

and my getData.aspx Page_Load method contains the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> test = new List<string>() { "Java", "Javascript", "sss", "sqre" };
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            jsSerializer.Serialize(test, sb);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            Response.Write(test.ToString());

        }
```

why even alert("function done") is not executed?  Why my autocomplete is not working? Can someone please help me?

Comment: can you debug 'getData.aspx' and see that it's really called and returns a value? p.s. you have another bug there: the $.getJSON method is asynchronous. meaning- it returns right away, and the success function is executed when the ajax call is completed. Therefore, the next line, which initializes the autocomplete, is executed after the *call* to 'getData', but *before* 'getData' returns. that means that 'test' is not yet initialized. you just have to move the initialization of the autocomplete to your ajax success function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $.getJSON("getData.aspx", null, function (json) {
          alert("function dome");
          $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
              source: json
          });
      });              
  });
```

Comment: @niao np. Just to explain what was wrong. I think the getJSON method wasn't working because you didn't include a value for the data parameter, so the null fixed that. Also, as sJhonny mentioned, the value for test wasnt available until the callback had fired, so the autocomplete wireup had to be inside the callback function.

Comment: I have exactly the same code and alert function does not fire. I use jquery-1.5.1.min.js

Comment: Is your ajax request returning a value result? You can check by inspecting the request using sometime like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: I used page method with [WebMethod()] attribute instead of Page_Load  and $.ajax method with type: "POST", contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" parameters and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use AJAX in that way, since you have no way of knowing when the request returns. You need to perform your actions within the callback:

```
$.getJSON("getData.aspx", {}, function (json) {
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({ source: json });
});
```

Also, you can use a remote datasource directly without having to call `$.getJson`:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({ source: 'getData.aspx' });
```

The downside of this approach is that it'll make an asynchronous any time it needs to fetch an updated data set. The first approach is better if you have a small set of data that is fixed, the second approach is better if you have a large dataset with results that need to be filtered.